# Selecting Features from the results of topology checker in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there is any way to select or extract features from topology checker plugin in qgis?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin does not allow generate a memory layer or other layer to export it. The plugin is a c++ core plugin

I suggest you to create a Feature Request to the qgis project

https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

I was just reading the code, and having a feature request, it can be approached during qgis hackmeetings or using a crowd funding.

regards

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advise and I have done it as you suggested.